# How to span relationships while filtering list in python django?

Tags: python, django, list, django-orm

I have a model called `UserInteraction` which has a foreign key with the field name as `interaction`. The Interaction model then has a foreign key, with the field name as `content`. Subsequently, `Content` model has FK, `content_type` which has a boolean field called `is_scored`.

Some of the queries, that I am doing, are:

```
user_interactions = UserInteraction.objects.filter(user=user).prefetch_related('interaction__content')

total_scored = user_interactions.filter(interaction__content__content_type__is_scored=True).count()
```

My `UserInteraction` model also has at_ended field and basically I had to groupby my rows of `UserInteraction` model by week. Post that, I added the weekly grouped data in a list (let's call that list as **weekly**). So, for example, weekly consists of week 1 list: `[<UserInteraction: LG.2016/3/27@laugh.guru - Play School - 1>]` and week 2 list: `[<UserInteraction: LG.2016/3/27@laugh.guru - Vanilla - 1>, <UserInteraction: LG.2016/3/27@laugh.guru - Hyperlink - 1>]`.

Combined, weekly list would look like `[[<UserInteraction: LG.2016/3/27@laugh.guru - Play School - 1>], [<UserInteraction: LG.2016/3/27@laugh.guru - Vanilla - 1>, <UserInteraction: LG.2016/3/27@laugh.guru - Hyperlink - 1>]]`.

For every week, I want to calculate `total_scored` (which has been calculated on a queryset - code pasted above).

I want to know, how can I do that for my list named 'weekly'? I tried a lot using list comprehension techniques but I could not find a way to span relationships while applying filter on list (using lambda) which I could do when I applied filter on a queryset.